# Listening on a network for data - React Native App and Server

Tags: javascript, database, react-native

I'm wanting to create a react-native app that pulls data from a database on the same local network but only when there is a change.

The only way I know how to do this currently is have a loop that pulls the same data down from the database every X seconds but surely this is taxing on the database system?

Is there a way of having the database system (server) send a tiny bit of data out across the network telling any of the **listening** devices that they should update.

## Question 1

Any information on the ***Broadcasting*** side? (the part that sends the information out that the database has changed)

## Question 2

Any information on the ***Listener*** side? (that looks for incoming data from the broadcaster saying that the database has changed and they should update)

## End Goal

I'm creating a system where If a button is clicked it updates a database and a react native app then displays where the button is clicked for this I need a server that runs a database that is updated when the buttons are pressed and a app that only calls to the server for the information when there's new information on it.

Comment: check out web sockets.

Comment: I found this so I'm glad I'm on the right track, I'm very new to this task so was wondering about if this is the correct way to going at it.